# Custom agenda sorting by CREATED date

Tags: org-agenda, sorting, org-journal

I put together the function below but it doesn't work. The problem is `get-text-property` returns nil for every task.

Any idea how to get the CREATED property and fix the entire thing?

```el
(defun jarfar/org-agenda-cmp-user-defined-created-date (a b)
  "Org Agenda user function to sort tasks based on CREATED property."
  (let* (
          (time-a (get-text-property 0 'CREATED a))
          (time-b (get-text-property 0 'CREATED b))
          (time-a (if time-a (org-time-string-to-time time-a) nil))
          (time-b (if time-b (org-time-string-to-time time-b) nil)))

    (if (and time-a time-b)
      (if (org-time< time-a time-b)
        -1
        (if (org-time> time-a time-b)
          1
          nil))
      (if time-a time-a time-b)
      )))
```

---

EDIT: Here is an example data file:

```
* Tasks
** TODO Task 1
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-07-23 Thu]
:END:

** TODO Task 2
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-06-15 Tue]
:END:

** TODO Task 3
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-05-22 Sat]
:END:

** TODO Task 4
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-06-01 Tue]
:END:
```

---

EDIT: Update to the function:

```el
(defun jarfar/org-agenda-cmp-user-defined-created-date (a b)
  "Org Agenda user function to sort tasks based on CREATED property."
  (let* (
          (marker-a (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
          (marker-b (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
          (time-a (if marker-a (org-entry-get marker-a "CREATED") nil))
          (time-b (if marker-b (org-entry-get marker-b "CREATED") nil))
          (time-a (if time-a (org-time-string-to-time time-a) nil))
          (time-b (if time-b (org-time-string-to-time time-b) nil)))

    (if (and time-a time-b)
      (if (org-time< time-a time-b)
        -1
        (if (org-time> time-a time-b)
          1
          nil))
      (if time-a time-a time-b)
      )))
```

Comment: What is `org-journal-create-re`? The name implies that it's a regex, not a text property. If you do `C-u C-x =` on the entry, does it report some sort of `created` text property?

Comment: I found some examples online which use regex in place of text property but I have not idea if these work. I tried different things, together with regex. I run this shortcut while pointing on TODO and it opened help buffer with charset/encoding info, but face was org-todo. When I did the same on CREATED prop the face is org-special-keyword. It didn't change anything when I put org-special-keyword in place of org-journal-created-re. The value returned by get-text-property is still nil. org-special-keyword shows up as a face for anything inside heading.

Comment: AFAIK, text properties are symbols. Go to your buffer, put the cursor somewhere and say `M-x describe-text-properties` to get the text properties at point.

Comment: Ok, I did that but it doesn't show anything specific to CREATED.

Comment: So that tells you there is no CREATED text property at that point. Should there be? How do you know?  If I were you, the next question I would ask myself is: I was expecting this text property to have been created  here - who should be creating that text property at this point in the buffer and why is it NOT creating it? Unfortunately, debugging is hard (but remote debugging is almost impossible).

Comment: It boils down to the question - how to get value of custom property from org heading?

Comment: You do it with `(get-text-property (point) 'CREATED)` from the buffer or with `(get-text-property 0 'CREATED s)` from a string. But if there is no such property there, you are going to get `nil`.

Comment: I see. It returns nil even though every task have this property. I add this prop by capture, it's not standard one.

Comment: Isn't it more likely that you are *NOT* adding this property and the fault lies with the capture? How do you *know* that you are adding it?

Comment: That's not the case. I updated post with test file and filter function. All tasks have CREATED property, `get-text-property` returns nil for each of them.

Comment: That's *NOT* a [text property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html#Text-Properties). That's an Org mode property. You get those with `org-entry-get`. See [Using the Property API](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Using-the-Property-API) for information on Org mode properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compare function is run on the agenda buffer, not the original org buffer. Various data from the original is inserted as text properties, but this doesn't include general org properties (as in things in the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer).

To retrieve generic data from an org entry, first get the position of the original entry (stored as the `org-marker` text property). Then use `org-entry-get` on that position:

```
(let ((a-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
      (a-time (org-entry-get a-pos "CREATED"))
      ))
```

Comment: It works, thanks! For some files I get sort: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, (23498 25072). Any idea why and how to handle this?

Comment: Sounds like somebody is expecting a marker but not getting one. Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to get a backtrace and see if you can find out where the bad data is coming from. Looking at those numbers it looks like a timestamp. `decode-time` says it points to 2018-10-19. Maybe you're accidentally passing a time instead of a position?

Comment: thx, I was able to catch and fix some errors in data. I updated the function in original post to reflect current state. Now I get error when there is empty properties list - but it's declared. Any idea to improve that func to do some check and prevent the error if the property is not there?

Comment: Might be better to ask a new question so you can put in more details about the error.

Comment: Related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60613/custom-agenda-sorting-by-custom-property-check-if-property-exist