# Agenda sort by custom org timestamp property not working

Tags: org-agenda

The comparison function below meant to compare headings using custom CREATED property which store org timestamp. The problem is, it doesn't work - the sorting fallback to next sorting strategy which is `alpha-up`.

```el
(defun jarfar/org-agenda-cmp-user-defined-created-date (a b)
  "Org Agenda user function to sort tasks based on CREATED property."
  (let* (
          (marker-a (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
          (marker-b (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
          (time-a (if marker-a (org-entry-get marker-a "CREATED") nil))
          (time-b (if marker-b (org-entry-get marker-b "CREATED") nil))
          (time-a (if (jarfar/is-org-timestamp time-a) (org-time-string-to-time time-a) nil))
          (time-b (if (jarfar/is-org-timestamp time-b) (org-time-string-to-time time-b) nil)))

    (if (and time-a time-b)
      (if (org-time< time-a time-b)
        -1
        (if (org-time> time-a time-b) 1 nil))
      (if time-a -1 1)
      )))

(defun jarfar/is-org-timestamp (arg)
  "Returns 't' if 'arg' is org timestamp string, otherwise returns nil."
  (and arg (stringp arg) (string-match org-ts-regexp0 arg)))
```

Example data file:

```
* Tasks
** TODO Task 1
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-03-01 Sun]
:END:

** TODO Task 2
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-05-01 Fri]
:END:

** TODO Task 3
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-07-01 Wed]
:END:

** TODO Task 4
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-06-01 Mon]
:END:
```

Any idea what is wrong with the function?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: I updated the post with error for every fail case.

Comment: Can you specify which functions are giving those errors in each case? `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` will enable a backtrace when the error triggers

Comment: I fixed some bugs and redefined the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was the problem, I simply over complicate it. `org-time` comparison functions work with output of `org-entry-get` not `org-time-string-to-time`.

```el
(defun jarfar/org-agenda-cmp-user-defined-created-date (a b)
  "Org Agenda user function to sort tasks based on CREATED property."
  (let* (
          (marker-a (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
          (marker-b (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
          (time-a (if marker-a (org-entry-get marker-a "CREATED") nil))
          (time-b (if marker-b (org-entry-get marker-b "CREATED") nil)))

    (if (and time-a time-b)
      (if (org-time< time-a time-b)
        -1
        (if (org-time> time-a time-b) 1 nil))
      (if time-a -1 1)
      )))
```